# Showing duplicate labels on X-Axis

Tags: ios, objective-c, charts, linechart, ios-charts

I am using the [Charts framework (danielgindi/Charts)](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts). My line chart is showing duplicated labels on x-axis, if is there is only one value available on my labels array(`xAxisLabels` in this case). See image below.

[image]

how can I ensure that the labels won't be duplicated? So if there is only one entry available on the labels array then it should display only one label on the left most side. other labels would be blank, which will be gradually filled upon availability on the labels array.

Here is the code that I have tried so far. Thank you very much for your help.

```
@property (nonatomic) LineChartView* chartView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<NSString *> *xAxisLabels;

- (void)configureChartViewIfNeeded {
    self.chartView.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = NO;
    self.chartView.legend.enabled = NO;
    self.chartView.minOffset = 28;

    self.chartView.xAxis.enabled = YES;
    self.chartView.xAxis.labelPosition = XAxisLabelPositionBottom;
    self.chartView.xAxis.labelTextColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.79];
    self.chartView.xAxis.gridColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.79];
    self.chartView.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = NO;
    self.chartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = NO;

    self.chartView.leftAxis.labelTextColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.79];
    self.chartView.leftAxis.gridColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.3];
    self.chartView.leftAxis.gridLineWidth = 1.0f;
    self.chartView.leftAxis.drawZeroLineEnabled = NO;
    self.chartView.leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = NO;
    [self.chartView.leftAxis setLabelCount:leftAxisLabelCount force:NO];
    self.chartView.leftAxis.drawTopYLabelEntryEnabled = YES;
    self.chartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0;
    JVNImpactMetricsFormatter *numberFormatter = [[JVNImpactMetricsFormatter alloc] init];  //My custom formatter
    [numberFormatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
    [numberFormatter setGroupingSeparator:@","];
    [numberFormatter setGroupingSize:3];
    numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1;
     self.chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = numberFormatter; //Will present integer values

    self.chartView.rightAxis.enabled = NO;

    self.chartView.dragEnabled = NO;
    self.chartView.scaleXEnabled = self.chartView.scaleYEnabled = NO;
    self.chartView.drawBordersEnabled = NO;
    self.chartView.doubleTapToZoomEnabled = NO;
    self.chartView.delegate = self;

    self.chartView.descriptionText = @"";
    [self.chartView animateWithXAxisDuration:0.3 yAxisDuration:0.3];
}


#pragma mark - IChartAxisValueFormatter

- (NSString * _Nonnull)stringForValue:(double)value axis:(ChartAxisBase * _Nullable)axis {
    return self.xAxisLabels[[@(value) intValue]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
self.chartView.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
```